# Not able to play the music when recived LocalNotification, when app is in background state in swift

Tags: ios, swift, localnotification, swift5

I'm scheduling up a Local Notification as an alarm for an app, where I'm setting music and vibration when local notification is received. When app is in foreground state everything is working fine, music is playing, vibration is there.

But when app is in background state only the default notification music i.e once only not in repeat and single vibration is occurring.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification) {

    //show an alert window
    var isSnooze: Bool = false
    var soundName: String = ""
    var index: Int = -1
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        isSnooze = userInfo["snooze"] as! Bool
        soundName = userInfo["soundName"] as! String
        index = userInfo["index"] as! Int
    }

    playSound(soundName)
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let mainVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as? HomeViewController
            mainVC?.notification = notification
            mainVC?.isFromNotificationDelegate = true

    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainVC!)
            self.window?.rootViewController = nav

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Register for notifications in AppDellegate.swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Sound | .Alert | .Badge, categories: nil))
    return true
}
```

Now, schedule your notification using following func, it will automatically play your custom sound whenever notification receieves

```
func localnotification (firedate:NSDate)  {
    var localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.fireDate = firedate
    localNotification.alertBody = "time to woke up"
    localNotification.soundName = "alarm.wav"

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
}
```

Comment: Will it play when app is in background state?

Comment: yes it will play, replace sound name with yours file name.

Comment: check replacing the sound with default & then see if its working or not